# create a "default" value for an object

Tags: javascript

Now before I ask my question, let me just say that I know strings are primitive on js and I know you can't add properties to them. Just to get that out of the way before anyone brings it up.

My question is if it would be possible to make an object have a kind of default value, in the same way a date object has it. With date objects if you do `typeof date` it will return `"object"`, but if you put it inside a string, it will automatically change to something that would look like `"Sun Jan 01 2000 01:23:45 GMT+0000 (ABC)"`.

Is it possible to create an object that would behave in the same way? Or is that behaviour exclusive to date objects?

One example of where I could use it is when running a function, I want to return a string by default, but also send extra data along with it. For example:

```
function getUser(index) {
    return {
        defaultVal: userNames[index],
        extraData: {points:userPoints[index]}
    }
}
alert("your name is "+getUser(userId))
//will alert the user's name, instead of json object
```

Comment: Can you please post samples of the code in question?

Comment: What do you mean by 'put it inside a string?'

Comment: @JoshBeam added an example, I hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding.  Perhaps you are looking for the .toString() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`alert's docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert),

> message is an optional string of text you want to display in the alert
>   dialog, or, alternatively, an object that is converted into a string
>   and displayed.

So, you need to override the default `toString` method, like this, to give represent your object in the `alert`.

```
function myString (value) {
    this.actualValue = value;
}

myString.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log("Inside myString.toString, returning", this.actualValue);
    return this.actualValue;
};

function getUser() {
    var myUser = new myString("Bruce Wayne");
    myUser.extraData = "I am BatMan!";
    return myUser;
}

alert(getUser());
```

[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL9s5/)

As per the [`toString docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Description),

> Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when
>   the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is
>   referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the
>   toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object.
>   If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString()
>   returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.

So, this new function, which we defined, will be called even in the expressions where you use the object like a string. For example,

```
console.log("The value of the Object is " + getUser());
```

Comment: I was just looking back at this question, and I was wondering, is it also possible to do this with numbers? It's still on-topic for this question, and I don't think it's worth it asking a whole seperate question, because I assume the answer is no, but is there a way to make an object return something other than `NaN` when used in `+varname`? So basically, can your suggested method be applied to numbers as well somehow? `Date()` has it, and it returns the UNIX timestamp then (when using `+new Date()`).

Comment: On second thought, I've [posted this as a seperate question anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23945748/1256925).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to override the `toString()` method.

```
getUser.prototype.toString() = function() {
    return this.stringRepresentation;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can actually add properties to strings, like this

```
String.prototype.foo=function(bar){
    return this+bar;
}

var str="hello, ";
alert(str.foo("world!"));
```

So I think what you might want be something like this

```
myObj={foo:"bar","hello":world,toString:function(){
    return this.foo+", "+this.world;
}};
```

and then instead of printing your `myObj`, you can print out `myObj.toString()`

Or in your case, something like this

```
getUser.prototype.toString=function(){
    return this.defaultVal+this.extraData.userPoints[index]
}
```