# Set a number return value for an object

Tags: javascript, object

I've previously [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20929300/1256925) a fairly similar question, and with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929414/1256925), I know it's possible to make objects that return strings when placed inside other strings. This would be some code based on that answer which would allow the object to have a custom string return value:

```
function myString(value) {
    this.String = value;
}
myString.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.String;
}
var strObj = new myString('Foo');
//>> strObj
//<< myString {String: "Foo", toString: function}
//>> strObj+''
//<< "Foo"
//What I want in addition to this:
//>> +strObj
//<< 42
```

I originally got the idea for that original question by seeing the effects of `Date` objects within strings. So, since there's another feature of `Date` objects that could be quite useful, I'd like to know if there's a way for me to do the same thing as `Date` objects do when used in an expression (being converted to a number):

```
+new Date(); //1401414068943
```

I'd like my `myString` object to do the same. I've tried to continue the mindset of the prototype `toString` in the object, but although there is a JS method to convert to strings, there's no method - only a native function - to convert non-numbers to strings.

So is it possible for me to do this 'automatic object-to-number conversion' for my own objects, or is this some kind of sorcery only available to `Date` because it's native to JS?

I'd like the syntax to then be

```
var strObj = new myString('Foo', 42);
```

if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the prototype method you are looking for that handles object to numeric conversion is [Object.prototype.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

It can be altered or customized just as you are altering `toString()`

Be aware that this sort of thing can be considered bad style when it may confuse other programmers (including yourself at a future date) as standard conversions can be redefined to behave differently than expected.

Comment: [Yup, that was exactly what I was looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/pL4bP/). I couldn't find it anywhere else when searching for "javascript convert to number".

Answer (score 2):

`toString` is the method that is invoked when an object is used in a string context (more exactly, when [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8) is called on it). And yes, there is a similar method that is invoked when an objet is used in a numeric context ([ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)): `valueOf`. If either doesn't exist, the other is used, for details see the [DefaultValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) algorithm.

```
function MyHybrid(str, num) {
    this.string = str;
    this.value = num;
}
MyHybrid.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.string;
};
MyHybrid.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.value;
};

var hybrid = new MyHybrid('Foo', 42)
String(hybrid) // "Foo"
Number(hybrid) // 42
```

However, it must be noted that `strObj+''`, which you have used for a conversion into a string, does **not** call ToString. The [`+` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) can both act on numbers and strings, and therefore does only call [ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) without a type hint - in which case `valueOf` is preferred (unless it is a `Date` object). `hybrid+''` is equivalent to `42+''` and will yield `"42"`.